# General question: After update to R 4.0.3, what is the best way to update packages?

Tags: r

My general question is:

After an update to R 4.0.3, what is the best way to update packages?

Can I somehow move all libraries from my old R version (3.5) to the new one?

Should I remove R 3.5?

What is the cleanest way to do this whithout getting package installation problems in the end?

Thanks for help!

Comment: See https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/upgrade-r-without-losing-your-packages/

Comment: Thanks! What if I already updated R? The packages are still in the old path? Can I still move them?

Comment: Supposed you're using RStudio on windows, then the new R version is already set to default there. Easiest would probably be to run `Rgui.exe`, which you might find under sth like following path: C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\bin\x64\ , and the use the method from the link above. After updating, the old R3.5.x folder is probably no longer necessary.